# Выбор правильной базы данных для О.К

Tags: sql, nosql

Хочу начать свой начать свой первый проект это создать создание базы данных для HR. Хочу реализовать web проект на nodejs. И мне тут предстоит выбрать, что будет лучше использовать NoSQL || SQL. Так как большого опыта не имею. Помогите выбрать правильную структуру БД.

Структура БД: Отделы, службы, сотрудники, контрактники, стаж и т.д.

Comment: Используйте файлы для начала. Не усложняйте ссамого начала проект. Решите его сначала без базы

Comment: Если данные структурированные (а у вас это именно так) выбирайте реляционную БД, т.е. SQL

Comment: @AzizUmarov простите, а как понять "использовать файлы" ?

Comment: @Mike спасибо за совет

Comment: А что обязательно база данных? Что нельзя просто данные записать в файл и считать их. Я сомневаюсь что у hr будут очень много данных чтоб нужна была субд

Comment: Сделайте политику, тесты, а база данных и прочее это детали. Вы слишком привязываетесь к деталям в самом начале. Постройте модель, классы, UI, а сохранение можно сделать в память тупо для начала.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Но тогда придется писать некий достаточно сложный слой, который будет работать с файлами. Как вы себе представляете реализацию поиска в них (без полного пребора). Как обновить запись где нибудь в середине файла, опять же не переписывая его целиком. А с любыми БД, даже просто встроенной вроде SQLIte это идет готовое из коробки

Comment: @Mike если говорить о коробке то и access в полне справится. Ведь основная проблема не в выборе СУБД, а в логике самой программы. Сохранить если надо будет в файл с json daными я не вижу никаких проблем. Считали все изменили. Сохранили все. Я понимаю для вас это сложно. Но не нужно концентрироваться на СУБД это деталь всего лиш. Засунуть все в список не составит проблем и вовсе. А сохранить его в файл может быть и сложно для вас.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Это не сложно, а скучно. И вместо того что человек будет решать свою основную задачу, ему придется тратить время на типовые действия с сравнением с массивом. Это загружает процессор и диск лишней работой. Увеличивается сложность кода, потенциально растет количество ошибок. И человек еще вдобавок не изучает SQL, который наверняка ему понадобится в будущих проектах. Лично я к файлам прибегаю только тогда, когда есть специфическая задача, требующая тонкой оптимизации по скорости

Comment: Я соглашусь с @Mike ом. Я не профи даже не мидл по SQL, только начал изучать, не знаю всех тонкостей структуры БД. Но стремлюсь. Спасибо за потраченное время